# How do I use imported ONNX model in BigQuery ML?

Tags: tensorflow, google-bigquery, pytorch, onnx

I've converted a huggingface pretrained model into onnx:

```
python3 -m transformers.onnx --model=sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2 onnx/
```

Imported it into BigQuery:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL ml.make_embeddings
OPTIONS(
  MODEL_TYPE='ONNX',
  MODEL_PATH="gs://my-bucket/all-MiniLM-L6-v2.onnx"
)
```

Now how do I know what the input should look like?

This throws error:

```
SELECT * FROM
ML.PREDICT(MODEL ml.all_minilm_l6_v2,(
SELECT 1 AS input_ids, 0 AS token_type_ids, 1 AS attention_mask, ['hello world'] AS sentences))
```

```
An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed. This is usually caused by a transient issue.
```

Answer (score 0):

the internal error you hit above is a known issue and a fix is being rolled out on our end. You can expect the fix live in about 2 weeks.

> Now how do I know what the input should look like?

Please check https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/getting-model-metadata#get_model_metadata for how to get model schema.